# Вопрос по Mega menu для Wodpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.

Сейчас постараюсь рассказать проблема.
Есть сайт на WP + Woocommerce + WPML.
Сейчас сделал мега меню на плагине Max Mega Menu
[image: Мега меню]

Оно сделано через Custom HTML и проблема в том, что если переключить язык на другой, то меню не переводится, приходится вручную прописывать все ссылки и названия элементов меню.
Я бы хотел, чтобы можно было выводить нужные категории и на других языках отображались категории в меню на нужном языке.
В этом плагине есть вывод категорий, но категории выводятся все, а хотелось бы выбирать.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Здравствуйте, вы [документацию](https://www.megamenu.com/documentation/wpml-setup/) читали и выполняли все описанные шаги?

Comment: Допустим я создаю мега меню, делаю синхронизацию, и это же меню на другом языке без мега меню, приходится делать заново структуру и создавать виджеты. А Custom Html я так понимаю не переводятся?